# Normalize an adjacency matrix twice

Tags: matrices, spectral-graph-theory, clustering, adjacency-matrix

I am working on a graph clustering problem and i've seen that applying two consecutive normalizations on the adjacency matrix gives much better performance than when applying a single one.

I first apply the symmetric normalization:

$$T = D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$$

Then apply row normalization on the resulting matrix:

$$S = D_T^{-1}T$$

I tried working out the overall formula of S w.r.t to A but it didn't yield anything particularly significant (i think). Here's the formula i ended up with:

$$s_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}}{\sqrt{d_j}\sum_k\frac{a_{ik}}{\sqrt{d_k}}}=\frac{a_{ij}}{a_{ij}+\sqrt{d_j}\sum_{k\neq j}\frac{a_{ik}}{\sqrt{d_k}}}$$

I know that when applied separately they have a connection with the graph cut problem but does it hold any meaning to apply the row normalization on the symmetric normalized adjacency matrix in the context of clustering?

Comment: Hi Qtip. The bit you worked out may be a useful starting point. I suggest enriching your post by showing what you have done. (Click "Edit" above.)